# Cleanly uninstall Rspec and use vanilla Unit::Test in Rails 3.x

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I was reading the Rails Tutorial and following along like a good drone installing everything the way it said and doing everything it told me. Then I realized I didn't like the book any more for a number of reasons and quit reading it. But I had already created my own project with Rspec installed as it told me to. Then I find out that Rspec is quite a bit more complicated than the built in Test::Unit and every other book I read is telling me how to use Test::Unit, including the excellent 'Rails Test Prescriptions' by Pragmatic. (I wish I'd started with them first.) Anywho, the book does teach Rspec a little bit but not until after you get past Test::Unit. Now I can't scrape Rspec out of my project. There is a 'rails generate rspec:install' but no uninstall and my tests now default to Rspec. I can force a unit test with 'rake test' but if I use 'rake' it goes to Rspec. There are other remnants of Rspec too, like in the --help for 'rails generate'. My concern is that as I get more involved with vanilla Test I'll find more problematic areas. I removed or renamed the files / folders generated by the installation. I also looked for changes to my config files but couldn't find any. I intend to consider Rspec down the road but for now I'd like to have a clean project to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already did this, but thought I would throw it out there just incase. Did you remove the RSpec references from you Gemfile?

Comment: Nevermind, I removed it from my tests but not my dev mode. You got it. I feel dumb.

Answer (score 5):

You can do following,
1) Remove spec directory
2) Remove all rspec related gems (capybara, faker, etc.) from the Gemfile
3) Run 'bundle clean --force' command to remove all unused gems and then run 'bundle install' again
4) Now 'bundle list' should show you all the gems except rspec related

Answer (score 0):

In config/application.rb , changed

```
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

to

```
require 'rails/all'
```